# Запуск событий в javascript

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток

вот хотел узнать можно так запустить событие?

например >>

```
window.open("http://google.ru");
```

но мне допустим  нужен не совсем линк

мне нужно например вот так,

это часть кода, запуск  в  javascript другого  javascript

```js
<script>
window.open();{сторонний javascript };
window.focus();
</script>
```

Еще пока полный код не проверял, можно так делать или не будет работать? что бы лишнее не копать глубоко и не тратить время,  хочу узнать, я методом тыкания проб и ошибок изучаю, собираю знания.

Comment: еще обычно так запускают  события <script>
  window.onload = function() {
    другой  javascript
  };
</script>
<iframe src="https://example.com/" style="height:60px"></iframe>
<img src="https://js.cx/clipart/yozhik.jpg?speed=1">

Comment: "можно так запустить событие" - Голова у программиста, чтобы думать, мозги - чтобы соображать, а пальцы - чтобы внятно объяснить на StackOverflow что ему нужно.

Comment: А `open()` не может принимать в качестве аргумента коллбэк?

Comment: @Byulent, нет, ему это и не нужно, он возвращает открытое окно

Answer (score 1):

В окне, открытом скриптом, выполнить код нельзя.

Это ограничение введено по соображениям безопасности.

Comment: ...если у них различаются origin

Answer (score 0):

```
Пример использования внешнего js скрипта:
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Пример использования функции jquery:
    <script>
    function check(invalue) {
        if (invalue.length > 40) $(.input).hide();              
    }
    </script>

При подключении внешнего js-файла все его функции становятся доступными:
    <script>
    check(invalue);
    </script>

Пример использования функции js внутри тега-строки <input>(получает значение строки при нажатии клавиши в данном элементе):
    <input type="text" name="value" class="input" onkeyup="check(this.value)" />
```